# I've got a dropdown menu that I would like to restrict access to based on PW input, but it's not dropping down as desired

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I've got it mostly working, but I am coming up short in my solution.
Here is my js:

```
function validateExportAccess(e) {
  // Prevent the dropdown from opening by default
  e.preventDefault(); //I suspect this may be the culprit but I don't want the dropdown to drop until it's unlocked

  // Check if dropdown is unlocked
  isExportUnlocked(function (unlocked) {
      if (unlocked) {
          // Exports dropdown menu is accessible on successful pw input
          $("#navbarDropdown").attr("data-toggle", "dropdown"); // This works but user has to click twice to display dropdown
          //$("#navbarDropdown").dropdown('show'); //This shows the dropdown but does not toggle the dropdown as desired
          //$(e.target).dropdown('toggle'); //also does not toggle dropdown menu
      } 
        else {
          // Show the modal for pw input if locked
          $('#passwordModal').modal('show');
      }
  });
}

function isExportUnlocked(callback) {
  $.ajax({
      url: '/export_unlocked',
      method: 'GET',
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function (response) {
          callback(response.unlocked);
      }
  });
}
```

And my html:

```
          <li class="nav-item dropdown" id="exportDropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" data-toggle=""  aria-expanded="false" data-toggle="" onclick="validateExportAccess(event)">Exports</a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" id="dropdownRight" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
              <%= link_to "Contacts", contacts_path(format: :csv), class: 'dropdown-item' %>
              <%= link_to "Cost Summary", broadcasts_path(format: :csv), class: 'dropdown-item' %>
              <%= link_to "Broadcasts Summary", broadcasts_path(format: :csv, special: true), class: 'dropdown-item' %>
            </div>
          </li>
```

why does it take two clicks on the Export button to drop the dropdown menu?
Is there a way to unlock this via rails and erb instead?

Here are the applicable controller methods:

```
  def export_verify
    if current_user.valid_password?(params[:password])
      session[:export_unlocked] = Time.current
      redirect_to session[:export_lock] || root_path
    else
      redirect_to root_path, alert: 'Incorrect Password, please try again.'
    end
  end

  def export_unlocked
    unlocked = session[:export_unlocked] && session[:export_unlocked] > 1.minutes.ago
    render json: { unlocked: unlocked }
  end
```